# Recall Doc2Vec in Spark and input vectors to Logical regression machine learning

Tags: apache-spark, gensim

I ran Gensim to train Doc2vec of the corpus. I need to extract the vector of each document as input data for Logical regression in spark.

Comment: What have you tried? What is blocking your progress? What wasn't clear from the `Doc2Vec` documentation at <https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html>?

Comment: I hope to recall the result of Doc2vec in spark. I don't know how to import vectors trained by Doc2vec to spark application. I am finding some code example to try.

Comment: Maybe I save the vectors of Doc2vec as csv file at first, then read this file from the spark application to use them.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Doc2Vec` model is in the variable `model`, each doc-vector is accessible by its key (the `tag` provided during training) via:

```py
model.docvecs[tag]
```

The array of all raw doc-vectors is available in:

```py
model.docvecs.vectors_docs
```

(If you used plain ints as tags for your documents during training, then each document's vector is at the int position that was supplied. If you used strings as tags instead, then the string tag corresponding to each position in that `vectors_docs` array is in the `model.docvecs.index2entity` list. If you used a mixture of ints and strings – which is very rare & not recommended except for experts – then the optimization used is more complex and you should check the source code for the full story.)